# the smallest number n that so that $\exists $ distinct $a_1,\cdots, a_n \in (2\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1} + 1), \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_i}=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, contest-math, egyptian-fractions

[This](https://pumac.princeton.edu/archives#2008) is PUMAC $2008$ Division A Number Theory problem $10$.

> What is the smallest number n that so that $\exists $ distinct $a_1,\cdots, a_n \in (2\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1} + 1), \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_i}=1$?

A solution I found online essentially reads as follows. One can't choose any number $n<8$ as $\dfrac{1}{a_1} + \cdots +\dfrac{1}{a_n} \leq \dfrac{1}{3}+ \dfrac{1}5 +\cdots + \dfrac{1}{15} < 1$. One can't choose 8 as one can multiply both sides by the least common multiple of the denominators to get an even number equal to an odd number. However, one can get 9 because $\sum_{i=1}^9 \dfrac{1}{a_i} = 1$ for $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_9) = (3,5,7,9,11,15,35,45,231).$

> I was wondering if there's a theoretic way to get this tuple (i.e. without using a computer program or brute force)? I think it has something to do with inequalities and that it's good to start with $3,5,7,\cdots, 19$ as the first possible tuple. Then one needs to gradually increase numbers somehow.

Comment: "A solution that I found online" : can you tell where in order not do duplicate efforts ?

Comment: See [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/) for a compendium of properties of these so-called "Egyptian fractions" (useful keyword...)

Comment: A detail : $\mathbb{N_{n \ge 1}}$ is slightly better than $\mathbb{Z_{n \ge 1}}$

Comment: Section 9.5 of [Egyptian fractions](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fractions/egyptian.html) written by Dr. Ron Knott.

Comment: @JeanMarie fine it's from the number theory section of the 2008 PuMAC.

Comment: @Apass.Jack thanks for the link. Could the answerers of this question have used a general algorithm to compute the given series of Egyptian fractions?